# Bulk rename directories with prefix Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to bulk rename directories with a prefix in Unix.  Prefix like abc-

So if current directory is 123, I want to make it abc-123, etc

I've tried

```
for d in $(find . -name '*' -type d) ; do
mv $d $(echo $d | sed 's/$d/abc-$d/g')
done
```

but that doesn't work.  Do very little shell scripting so any help would be appreciated. 
rename command is not available

Thank you!

Comment: Which shell do you use? In zsh, for example, this is simple - `zmv -Q '(*)(/)' 'abc-$1'`. In bash it's more complicated and to do it properly requires a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for d in $(find . -depth -type d); do
    b=$(basename $d)
    p=$(dirname $d)
    mv -v $d $p/abc-$b
done
```

Note that the `-depth` argument is really important:  it ensures that the directories are processed from bottom to top, so that you rename child directories before their parents.  If you don't do that then you'll end up trying to rename paths that no longer exist.

Also I recommend replacing line 4 with

```
    echo "mv -v $d $p/abc-$b"
```

and running that version of the loop first so you can see what it will do before trying it for real.

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you!  The verbose flag wasn't supported but that is fine, additionaly, I'm only renaming top level directories.  Marking as answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you could do it with one line and `find -exec` like so,

```
find . -type d -depth -execdir mv {} abc-{} \;
```

Comment: +1, but to better support the recursive case, use `-execdir` instead and add `-depth`.

Comment: `mv: rename . to abc-.: Invalid argument`; `mv: rename ./dir to abc-./x-dir: No such file or directory.`

Comment: `-depth -execdir` will fix all but excluding `.`.